# Overlay permissions caused by Play Store App?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I am using Android 6.0.1. I am getting intermittently Overlay Permissions dialog when I install my apps. I have narrowed it down to when I ask for permissions for my app and when the shortcut created message for the App Store app wants to show. If I wait to open my app till after that message no Overlay Permission Dialog shows. Problem is I have googled and can not find a solution. I looked for overlay permissions for the Play Store app but can not find Play Store App listed in the App Manager.

Any Ideas? Seems like a bug with the Play Store App.

Comment: Did some more testing and made sure for google play services draw on foreground enabled. I  noticed that if I open my app and let the message from play store show when I waited to ok my permissions the shortcut is not created on the home screen but elsewhere. If I wait  to open my app till after the shortcut message (Toast maybe?) then the shortcut is put on the home screen. Not sure if that helps anyone. FYI this problem never shows up when installing via Android Studio on my device while debugging.

Comment: I mentioned it to someone at google so hopefully I get an answer. I do not have a Toast message from my app trying to show itself above the permissions dialogs so that is not it. I have not tried setting my target api to 22 yet to see if the other permissions dialog is better. I mention that because the Google Earth permissions is different in that before you can start the download it asks from permissions so I figure it does not overlap with the shortcut message from Play Store install of the app.